# « il y a encore dix minutes » versus « il y a déjà dix minutes »

Tags: expressions

I came up with two example sentences, using « encore » in one and « déjà » in the other. Do I correctly understand their meanings?

> 1 : Albert est passé par ici il y a **encore** dix minutes. Tu pourras le rattraper si tu te hâtes.

I used « encore » with the meaning of "**just**" for emphasis. The sentence can be paraphrased as:

> 1+ : Albert vient tout juste de passer par ici il n'y a que dix minutes.

On the other hand, I placed « déjà » here to express the idea of "ten (**long**) minutes ago" – for the sake of emphasis again.

> 2 : Albert est passé par ici il y a **déjà** dix minutes. Tu ne risques pas de le rattraper.

Comment: I think the use of "encore" in this kind of sentences is kind of tricky... I'm personnaly not sure of it's exact meaning in your sentence number one... I would only understand what you meant by hearing the second part "Tu pourras le rattraper". At work, we use to say "dans le doute, reboot", but here, I would say "dans le doute, trouve un autre moyen", even if the rhyme disappears... ;)

Comment: @Random How do you feel about saying "il y a seulement dix minutes" or "il n'y a que dix minutes"? Merci.

Comment: This might/might not have anything to do with why it's being said that "encore" doesn't seem to work in this case, but I've noticed that "il y a déjà" in the "already" sense is often found following the *passé composé* whereas "il y a encore" in the "until just a few" sense is often used following the *imparfait* and/or states of being [where, perhaps coincidentally, you could fit "encore" directly after the verb instead] (Albert passait [encore] par ici/était [encore] ici/ il y a [encore] dix minutes.)

Comment: @LUNA it sounds very natural, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sentence, using *juste* or *à peine* instead of *encore* would be clearer.

> Albert est passé par ici il y a juste dix minutes. Tu pourras le rattraper si tu te hâtes.

The second sentence is fine and match your goal.

Comment: "tout juste" may be a good one too !

Comment: A native French speaker in my office tends to use « encore » in this exact fashion. So it has rubbed off on me, ha-ha. Merci.

Comment: *Encore* is not to be completely ruled out. *Il y a encore dix minutes, Albert est passé par ici* is idiomatic French, like the more usual *il était encore là il y a dix minutes.*

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed, "encore là" sounds much more natural to me than "encore dix minutes"

Comment: @LUNA Yeah, some people use it, as some people say "tu sais me passer le sel ?" instead of "tu peux me passer le sel ?". It doesn't seem natural to me, except in the way jlliagre says "encore ici", where it means "he was still there"...

Comment: @Random, *Tu sais me passer le sel* is correct and idiomatic French in Belgium.

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, I guess using "savoir" is a regionalism. I've only heard it in few places, but can't remember where. I've never heard it near Nice neither near Nantes. But maybe near Marseille or Toulouse.

Comment: @Random That couldn't be in Marseile or Toulouse, unless you met tourists. This is exclusively a Belgian French specificity.

Comment: On the other hand, is there another expression synonymous with "il y a **déjà** dix minutes"? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA I can't think of any off-hand.

Comment: Oh, I see. What do you think of this construction, then? "Albert est passé par ici  il n'y a même pas dix minutes."

Comment: @LUNA The construction is correct and idiomatic. *Juste* means precisely here while *même pas dix minutes* is "not even ten minutes ago".